# Where can I find information within Spark UI on what a Spark stage is doing?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I'm trying to see if there's anything I can do to speed up a Spark job. I'm somewhat new to using Spark so I'm not sure what I'm looking at in Spark UI. I've found the job and stage that's running, but I can't see what's making it take so long. I just see in the stage's Event Timeline that it's all focused on Executor Computing Time. In the DAG Visualization, I see a lot of ShuffleQueryStages, Sorts, and WholeStageCodegens. The notebook I've run has quite a few left joins so I think those make sense. I'm wondering though if the job is focused on a Coalesce or WriteFiles. Any way to check that?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the SQL tab for more information using the job id of the job. This should show you all the info related to which table is being read and the join strategy being used etc.

You can also check the stages for a long-running job; the metrics will show you the difference between the max time and median time taken by the tasks. If there's a big difference, then your data partitioning is causing one or more tasks to be overloaded. You'd need to repartition your data to fix this.